Sorting Months inside a Multi index groupby object
Its the sample input. i wanted to group  according to the Year column,and wanted to use value counts on month column, then to sort the 'month' column according to the month order.



Year
month




2000
Oct


2002
Jan


2002
Mar


2000
Oct


2002
Mar


2000
Jan



I did this:
df.groupby(['Year'])['month'].value_counts()
i got the following output:



year
month




2000
Oct             2



Jan              1


2002
Mar              2



Jan                1



now i need to sort the month in the original month order.what can i do?
i want the following output:



year
month




2000
Jan             1



Oct             2


2002
Jan             1



Mar               2




Can you change the month column to the month number instead of name?

try sort_index

You can use groupby() and sort_values(by=['Year', 'month']):
import pandas as pd


def _sort_month(df):
    month_order = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    df['month'] = pd.Categorical(df['month'], categories=month_order, ordered=True)
    GB = df.groupby(['Year'])['month'].value_counts()
    G = GB.reset_index(name='count')
    res = G.sort_values(by=['Year', 'month'])
    res.set_index(['Year', 'month'], inplace=True)
    return res[res['count'] > 0]


df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2000, 2002, 2002, 2000, 2002, 2000],
                   'month': ['Oct', 'Jan', 'Mar', 'Oct', 'Mar', 'Jan']})

print(_sort_month(df))



Prints
            count
Year month       
2000 Jan        1
     Oct        2
2002 Jan        1
     Mar        2


You can reindex with a sorted index that takes the correct order of dates into account using datetime:
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Year": [2000, 2002, 2002, 2000, 2002, 2000, 2000],
        "Month": ["Oct", "Jan", "Mar", "Oct", "Mar", "Jan", "Dec"],  # Dec/2000 added to OP
    }
)

df = df.groupby(["Year"])["Month"].value_counts()

df = df.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        sorted(df.index, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(f"{x[0]}/{x[1]}", "%Y/%b")),
        names=["Year", "Month"],
    )
)

2000  Jan      1
      Oct      2
      Dec      1
2002  Jan      1
      Mar      2


Code
Convert index to datetime only when sorting with key parameter of sort_values function.
out = (df.groupby(['Year'])['month']
         .value_counts()
         .sort_values(key=lambda s: pd.to_datetime(
             s.index.map(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, x))), format='%Y %b')
                     )
)

out
Year  month
2000  Jan      1
      Oct      2
2002  Jan      1
      Mar      2
Name: count, dtype: int64

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Year': [2000, 2002, 2002, 2000, 2002, 2000], 
        'month': ['Oct', 'Jan', 'Mar', 'Oct', 'Mar', 'Jan']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).astype('str')


You can form a datetime with to_datetime, then reorder with argsort+iloc:
out = df.iloc[np.argsort(pd.to_datetime(df.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}-{x[1]}'),
                                        format='%Y-%b'))]

Output (using @e-motta's example):
Year  Month
2000  Jan      1
      Oct      2
      Dec      1
2002  Jan      1
      Mar      2
Name: count, dtype: int64

Intermediates:
# pd.to_datetime(df.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}-{x[1]}'), format='%Y-%b')
DatetimeIndex(['2000-10-01', '2000-12-01', '2000-01-01', '2002-03-01',
               '2002-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

# np.argsort(pd.to_datetime(df.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}-{x[1]}'), format='%Y-%b'))
array([2, 0, 1, 4, 3])

